# i want to get user data from api but it show me it is null

Tags: flutter

i call the provider in each index and i gave it an initial value if it is null but still have null error
(all data shown in console but not in app  )

Error Message

```
The getter 'name' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: name
```

this is profile code which i stored user's data in each index

```
Expanded(

                                              child: Text(
                                                 userProvider.user.name==null?'':userProvider.user.name ,

                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          index == 1
                                              ? Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      userProvider.user.email== null? '' :userProvider.user.email,

                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : index == 3
                                                  ? Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                              16),
                                                      child: Container(
                                                        child: Text(
                                                        userProvider.user.phone== null? '' :userProvider.user.phone,

                                                        ),
                                                      ),


              )
```

and this is user provider for login

```
Future<dynamic> login(String email, String password) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> body = {'email': email, 'password': password};

    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    print('Starting request');
    http.Response response = await http.post(Environment.userLogin,
        body: json.encode(body), headers: Environment.requestHeader);
    print('Completed request');
    print('user login response : ${response.body}');
    Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
    var results;
    if (res['code'] == 200) {
      // login successful
      _user = User.fromJson(res['message']);
      results = true;
    } else {
      print(res['error']);
      // login failed;
      results =
          FailedRequest(code: 400, message: res['error'], status: false);
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return results;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your login method return results instead of _user or res.

Comment: it is my function in login screen , so if i replace results by res the proplem will end ?

signIn() async {
     await userProvider.login(
        _userNameController.text, _passwordController.text);
        Navigator.pushReplacement( widget._context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomTabScreen()));

Comment: Assuming the value is within the response.body, then what you need to do is return res or you could do something like ```_userData = User.fromJson(res[YOUR_NAMED_KEY_WHICH_CONTAIN_CORRECT_PROPERTY])``` then return _userData